# meagre and residual set

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume we have a complede metric space. Then there is no meagre and residual subset.

I don't really see the conclusion of the proof.
Let's call $A$ this subset and assume that it is residual and meagre. Then since the space is complete we have that $A$ is dense and since it is meagre there ersits subsets $A_n$ such that $A=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n$ and every $A_n$ is nowhere dense.

Now the proof that I have says that it contradict Baire's THM but I don't see how. May be I am looking at another version?

Thanks

I found another proof:
Assuming $A$ meagre and residual then $X=A\bigcup (X/A)$ and so the space is meager. Here I also have a problem. What's going wrong if the whole space is meager?

Comment: What has Baire's theorem to say about complete metric spaces?

Comment: $(X,d)$ complete metric space, $(A_n)_{n\geq 1}$ closed s.t. $\bigcup A_n$ contains an open ball so $\exists n\geq 1 : A_n$ contains the open ball

Comment: And if $A$ is meagre and comeagre, that means ...?

Comment: this was my question ;)

Comment: Okay, let's try from "What's going wrong if the whole space is meager?". If the whole space is meagre, that means, by definition, that - what?

Comment: $X=\bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n, A_n$ nowhere dense. and? I can't say that much about the union of the $A_n$ since it is not finite... I don't get the point

Comment: You can say something about the union. It's $X$, the entire space. And you can assume $A_n = \overline{A_n}$.

Comment: Maybe so... choosing $A_n$ closed I use Baire to find an open ball in the union and so I know that there exists an $A_n$ that contains this ball. Now since A_n is nowhere dense int(closure($A_n$)) is empty and this is a contradiction. But I still don't know why can I assume $A_n =$closure($A_n$)

Comment: If $\bigcup A_n = X$, then $\bigcup A_n = \bigcup \overline{A_n}$.

Comment: Does it follow from the completeness of the space?

Comment: What? The identity above is general. You always have $\bigcup A_n \subset \bigcup \overline{A_n}$ since $A_n \subset \overline{A_n}$, and if the potentially smaller union already is the entire universe, it follows that the unions are equal. The completeness of the space enters only at the end, where we use Baire to find a contradiction.

Comment: $X$ is the entire universe, nothing outside exists. You're thinking of the closure of $A_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (but then you'd still have $\bigcup [1/n,1] = (0,1] \neq [0,1]$), however, $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't exist, only $(0,1)$.

Comment: Ok I saw now my mistake.. Thank you very much!! :)